# Iterate through named range and update values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, named-ranges, setvalue

I need to iterate through a named range in Google Sheet and update the value based on other named ranges.

I have this now and I'm getting an error on line 13

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var FreeCopiesTarget = ss.getRangeByName('FreeCopiesTarget');
  var CostPerCopy = ss.getRangeByName('CostPerCopy');
  var FreeCopies = ss.getRangeByName('FreeCopies');

  var values = FreeCopiesTarget.getValues();

 for (var counter = 0; counter <= 4; counter++) {
   var cost = CostPerCopy.getValues()[counter][0] * FreeCopies.getValues()[counter][0];
   var r = FreeCopiesTarget.getValues()[counter][0];
   r.setValue(cost);
 }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you want to set the value in the `FreeCopiesTarget` range, change `var r = FreeCopiesTarget.getValues()[counter][0]` to `var r = FreeCopiesTarget.getCell(counter + 1, 1);`.

Comment: I would need to know more about the ranges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Iamblichus answer, I tweaked as follows and it works as expected.

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var FreeCopiesTarget = ss.getRangeByName('FreeCopiesTarget');
  freeCopiesValues = FreeCopiesTarget.getValues();
  var CostPerCopy = ss.getRangeByName('CostPerCopy').getValues();
  var FreeCopies = ss.getRangeByName('FreeCopies').getValues();
  
  for (var counter = 0; counter <= 4; counter++) {
    var cost = CostPerCopy[0][counter] * FreeCopies[0][counter];
    freeCopiesValues[0][counter] = cost;
  }
  FreeCopiesTarget.setValues(freeCopiesValues);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

`r` is a value from a cell, which can be a `Number`, `Boolean`, `String`, or a `Date`. None of these includes the method [setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue). `r` should be a [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) instead.

#### Code sample:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var FreeCopiesTarget = ss.getRangeByName('FreeCopiesTarget');
  freeCopiesValues = FreeCopiesTarget.getValues();
  var CostPerCopy = ss.getRangeByName('CostPerCopy').getValues();
  var FreeCopies = ss.getRangeByName('FreeCopies').getValues();
  for (var counter = 0; counter <= 4; counter++) {
    var cost = CostPerCopy[0][counter] * FreeCopies[0][counter];
    freeCopiesValues[0][counter] = cost;
  }
  FreeCopiesTarget.setValues(freeCopiesValues);
}
```

#### Note:

It's not best practice to use `getValues` iteratively. It's preferrable to get all values at once and work with the resulting 2D array, as shown in the sample above.

Comment: I'm getting an error
Error TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined onEdit @ Code.gs:10

on this line
   var cost = CostPerCopy.getValues()[counter][0] * FreeCopies.getValues()[counter][0];

Comment: @StephenSaid My bad, I mixed up `[0]` and `[counter]` in my sample. I fixed that, I hope it works now.